# iOS Safari loads outdated javascript

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, vite, chunks

### Problem

Safari on iOS tries to load memory-cached `javascript` that does not exist in HTML

On clean run - everything works fine.
After publishing any update - Safari loads all the new files + old cached that is not referenced anywhere

### Context

React app, Vite as a bundler.
Without "chunking" everything works fine.
With "chunking" everything works everywhere except Safari iOS

### Steps to reproduce

1. Add simple chunking:

- `node_modules` goes to `vendor`
- everything else goes to `index`

```js
rollupOptions: {
    output: {
        entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
        manualChunks: (id: string) => {
            if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                return 'vendor';
            } else {
                return 'bundle';
            }
        },
        chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
            const hash = createHash('md5')
                .update(Object.values(chunkInfo.moduleIds).join())
                .digest('hex')
                .substr(0, 6);
            return 'assets/[name].' + hash + '.js';
        },
    },
},
```

2. Create initial build (lets call it "build V1")

- `dist/assets/index.SBYBNO79.js`
- `dist/assets/vendor.b1e99d.js`

[image]

Open up in iOS - everything works fine

3. Make any kind of an update, rebuild (call it "build V2")

- `dist/assets/index.-9z7R_h8.js` (updated)
- `dist/assets/vendor.b1e99d.js` (same)

[image]

4. Now when iOS Safari loads webapp - it fetches all the new stuff from new HTML

But it also loads old `index.SBYBNO79.js`, while there is no mention of it in the HTML

[image]

[image]

### Thoughts

I wouldn't be bothered by it too much, but it crashes the app as it is out of sync with `vendor` bundle.

One of the options might be - to disable caching completely. But this is the point - I want to have javascript that is referenced from HTML to be cached.

Happens only on iOS Safari (mobile phone)

I tried to debug it for already 2 weeks, googled everything. Managed to narrow it down to this "extra" javascript request.

Would appreciate a lot any hint/direction.